# Disable input to a text box in GTk python

Tags: python, user-interface, gtk

I was developing a simple calculator in python using Gtk. In that calculator, if an expression such as `4*3` is entered and `=` is pressed, the result is displayed. But after that, if any other button is pressed, the number is appended on the screen (ie) if i press `4*3` `=` it shows `12`, after which i press 3 and i get `123`. I used

```
tb.set_editable(False)
```

but it stopped only the keyboard inputs, and the problem persists when i press any button. I want to change it such a way that if a new entry is pressed,the screen should clear...

Please help me on what i can do....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a variable that is initially set as False, say we call it say calculated.

In your key press event callback:

- If the key press is '=' append the calculated value and set calculated to True.
- If calculated is True and the key press is not '=' clear the value before setting it and set calculated to False.

Comment: so should i pass the value of `calculated` to the button_clicked function?

Comment: It depends how the rest of your code is laid out.Generally GUI code is made of classes so calculate would be a self.calculated attribute, on the class instance that contains the control that is displaying the value.